# NodeJS - req.params is undefined

Tags: node.js, angular

I need to get data by id from server.
I wrote a service by Angular 2:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { AppConfig } from '../appConfig';
import { JwtService } from './jwt.service';

@Injectable()
export class MemberService {

  constructor(
      private http: Http,
      private appConfig: AppConfig,
      private jwtService: JwtService) { }

  getMembersById(id: number) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Token ' + this.jwtService.getToken());

    return this.http.get(this.appConfig.urlServer + '/members/' + id, { headers: headers })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }
}
```

A code my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const nconf = require('./config');
const tables = require('./create_tables');
const routes = require('./routes');
const passport = require('passport');
const app = express();

const port = nconf.get('port');
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || port));

tables.create_tables();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extend: false
}));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
app.use(flash());

require('./passport/passport')(passport);

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(app.get('port'));

module.export = app;
```

Also I created `index.js` which set the routes for the app:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express();
const members = require('./members');

router.use('/members', members);

module.exports = router;
```

And I made the method in the `members.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const nconf = require('../config');
const connection = mysql.createConnection(nconf.get('db'));
const token = require('../middlewares/token');
const router = express();

router.get('/:id', token.required, getGroupsById);

module.exports = router;

function getGroupsById(res, req) {
  console.log(req.params);
}
```

Id is a number. Then I send it to my server but when I want to see got parameters I have the error:
`undefined`

I cannot understand where I made the errors. I seached in the stackoverflow answers and it don't help to me for resolving my problem.
Perhaps, somewhere I made the errors and now I cannot find it.
Please, help to me anybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrongly defined the signature of `getGroupsById`, it should be `(req, res)` instead of `(res, req)`

Correct signature:

```
function getGroupsById(req, res) {
   console.log(req.params);
}
```

Comment: Ooopps, a error is very and very silly. I don't see it because of my inattention . Many thanks for answer.